# Xamarin: How to get PeopleApi.GetCurrentPerson(client) and not have it return null

Tags: android, null, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've seen this question on dozen places on stackoverflow and none of them have the same answers or provide me with any solution...

I am using Xamarin but it shouldn't be that much different from Java.. so :)

Ive tried all the possible builders with all scopes:

```
var builder = new GoogleApiClientBuilder (activity, this, this);
            builder.AddApi (Android.Gms.Plus.PlusClass.Api);
            builder.AddApi (PlusClass.Api);
            builder.AddApi (api);
            builder.AddScope (PlusClass.ScopePlusLogin);
            builder.AddScope (PlusClass.ScopePlusProfile);
            builder.AddScope(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"));
            builder.AddScope(new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"));
            builder.AddScope (something);
            builder.AddScope (secondscope);
            builder.AddScope (mescope);
            client = builder.Build ();
```

using the "load visible..:

```
public void OnConnected (Android.OS.Bundle connectionHint)
        {
            PlusClass.PeopleApi.LoadVisible(client, null).SetResultCallback(this);
```

got my sha1 correctly in the developers console with deep linking enabled, got google+ api on,

and in OnConnected i call:

```
var accountname = PlusClass.AccountApi.GetAccountName (client);
var person = PlusClass.PeopleApi.GetCurrentPerson (client);
```

and account DOES return the correct adress
and person is still null! after a gazillion tries! please help me!

how can i get a correct "Person" response instead of null.. what have i done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the correct key of my keystore in the API console...

BUT when you DEBUG you are not using the correct keystore... so the sha1 of your DEBUG is different! so you need to have another access key in your https://console.developers.google.com/project/390400353744/apiui/credential..!
it will work in appstore! but not on debug ;)